# Best way to layout a Grid of List items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to layout a list of five items: 2 on top of the screen, 1 in the middle, 2 on the bottom (basically the green, red, black, orange, and purple squares below, and you can page horizontally through more of these pages):

[image]

I am trying to use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager, however I am confused how to set the height of my list_item to be 1/3 the height of the screen (does this involve weight?).

Am I going about this right? Any direction appreciated; I am new to Android dev. Thanks.

Update: I made progress by nesting horizontal linear layouts within one encompassing vertical linear layout. Now I believe I need this to be the list_item, and fill a horizontally-paged list with these items (definitely want to use RecyclerView in conjunction with one of its layout managers.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set span of gridlayout dynamically. Alternatively you can use [Lucas Rochas TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/) lib which is equipped with different types of layout.